# Regex invert selection

Tags: python, regex, parsing, inverse-match

I looked around quit a bit but was unable to find an answer to this question.

I'm trying to select everything from a string **except** white spaces that repeat over a certain number of times. I've found a regex to select the white spaces, and what I was hoping for was an easy way to get the exact inverse of this, but I haven't found a way to do that yet. I'm ultimately going to implement this in python if that matters.

Below is my test string, current regex, and link to the regex test site I was using.

[Current regex](https://regex101.com/r/LBK9B5/1)

test string:

```
'All: Day and Night                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Vulnerabilities\\Personnel vulnerabilities\\Outdoor vulnerability                                                                                                                                                                                                1E-09                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          /AvgeYear                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      \x1a'
```

Regex:

```
[ ]{50,}
```

Comment: Like this? `\S+(?:[ ]{1,49}\S+)*` https://regex101.com/r/ZKq68U/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird yea exactly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match 1+ non whitespace chars, and optionally repeat 1-49 spaces and 1+ non whitespace chars.

```
\S+(?:[ ]{1,49}\S+)*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZKq68U/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VdHPLs)

Example

```
from pprint import pprint
import re

regex = r"\S+(?:[ ]{1,49}\S+)*"
s = "All: Day and Night                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Vulnerabilities\\\\Personnel vulnerabilities\\\\Outdoor vulnerability                                                                                                                                                                                                1E-09                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          /AvgeYear                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\x1a'"

pprint(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
['All: Day and Night',
 'Vulnerabilities\\\\Personnel vulnerabilities\\\\Outdoor vulnerability',
 '1E-09',
 '/AvgeYear',
 "\\x1a'"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same regex and just `re.sub` your match to a single space.

```
re.sub(r'[ ]{50,}', ' ', string)
#'All: Day and Night Vulnerabilities\\Personnel vulnerabilities\\Outdoor vulnerability 1E-09 /AvgeYear \x1a'
```

If you want it as a list, simply use the same regex and use `re.split()` instead of `re.sub()`

```
re.split(r'[ ]{50,}', string)
#['All: Day and Night', 'Vulnerabilities\\Personnel vulnerabilities\\Outdoor vulnerability', '1E-09', '/AvgeYear', '\x1a']
```

Comment: this also gets me there, though I get a single string returned, which isn't ideal, but I should have specified

Comment: @SuperStew Do you want a `list`?

Comment: yea that's better for the rest of my code

Comment: @SuperStew Updated to output list.